# Curve fit with three points with a given slope

Tags: matlab, math

This might be of math problem than Matlab. Nonetheless, here is my problem.

[image]

so, I have a data set represented by the green curve.  It's usually linear, but sometimes it can have a slight curvature.  Then, I have two additional points: the red and the blue.  The red is far out in the negative.  Its amplitude is 30~100 bigger than the X value of the green circle and it's always on the X-axis.  The blue circle is always on the Y-axis.

I need a curve that fits the red, the blue, and the green circles, but there are two more constraints:

1. Blue curve can't be negative
2. where the blue curve meets the green curve, I want the slopes of them to be the same (smooth transition)

The red point doesn't have to be on the Y-axis, but asymptotic to zero and very close to zero at the red circle.

I have tried different inverse functions such as exponential, polynomial, 1/something, etc., but without a slope constraint, the end-result tends to have a cusp at the green point and it causes a problem for an overall analysis in which this curve-fitting function is used.

Can this be done?

Comment: Add the slope constraint as another equation.  Lagrange multiplier would be  a good way to express it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking an answer from

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523269/three-point-curve-fit-with-a-specificed-slope-at-one-point][1]

This uses the fact that it passes three points and at one point, its slope is known.  With the four equations and a generic irrational/exponential function, I was able to create a reasonable curve-fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to roughly match the slope and you have access to the data points of the green curve (not just the green dot), you can use multiple points of the green curve in the fitting function together with the blue and red point. That should produce a curve that passes through all the points and pretty much match the slope in the green point.

Clearly, if you need to match the slope with mathematical precision, you need to set up another constraint equation as it was suggested by duffymo.